# Link doesn't call JS function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Interesting. I have 2 links calling 2 JS functions - the first works , the second - doesn't. It only calls function addns() when the argument is empty. Otherwise nope...

PHP:

```
 while ($row_mem = mysqli_fetch_array($mem)) { 
 $membs[] = $row_mem['username'];
 $membs_id[] = $row_mem['user_id'];

 }

 }  

 //FIRST FOREACH CALL PROPERLY
 foreach($membs_id as $val_id) {
 echo"<a href='javascript:addms($val_id)'><img src='$pcheck' width='66' height='68'
 border='1' class='currmem'/></a>&nbsp;";
 }


//THIS ONE DOESN'T 
foreach($membs as $mes_id) {
echo"<a href='javascript:addns($mes_id)'>$mes_id</a>&nbsp;";
}
```

JS:

```
 function addms(msid) { 
 var addm = msid;
 alert(addm);
 }

function addns(nsid) { 
var addn = nsid;

alert(addn);




}
```

I cannot see any error - thanks for comments !

Comment: Could you post a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar, demo?

Comment: Why do you have the `$(document).ready()` in there?

Comment: @JaredFarrish Because it's jQuery...

Comment: No, why do you think you need it? It's usually only used to bind an anonymous function to a page load (after the document is, well, ready), not from within a function fired from an element's click handler.

Comment: What does the HTML look like once PHP is done with it? Is `$mes_id` a string? If so, it may need quotes.

Comment: @David Thomas http://jsfiddle.net/Q8M9F/1/

Comment: @JaredFarrish Removed - it doesn't make a difference....

Comment: Your fiddle needs fixing: http://jsfiddle.net/Q8M9F/3/ (You had it running using MooTools `onLoad` handler.)

Comment: What @Brandon was saying is that if the `$mes_id` is not a number (say, `adds1` instead of `1`), you will need to put quotes around it in the PHP output for the browser to use. This is meaningful, otherwise you'll get a JS parse error.

Comment: @MrX He *is* focusing, and asking you a perfectly reasonable question.

Comment: @Jarred Nope...doesn't work on my page - the thing is - I've got exactly similar foreach loop and it's calling the function properly...strange. I can only call adns function when it's empty: adns(). When I pass an argument in it - it doesn't call. But my second link calls another function written exactly the same...

Comment: We need to see the exact HTML in the page source the browser sees.

Comment: @Jarred Ok I'll update the question.

Comment: Updated - check this out guys...

Comment: I have a feeling once you look at the markup you may spot the problem. If not, try using a console like Firebug (in Firefox) or Chrome Console to debug JS errors.

Comment: You're a bit hard headed. JS runs on the browser *using* the output of the PHP; use the *actual markup* to debug what the *browser* is doing, then find out how to fix it on the *server*.

Comment: Can you post the HTML that this spits out?

Comment: @NickBrunt - *sigh* Please read the comments above yours.

Comment: @Jarred I've checked it in FF debugger - it says - $mes_id is not defined !? But it clearly is defined..

Comment: @JaredFarrish Ok, no need to sigh.  We both want the same thing :)

Comment: @MrX If the actual name `$mes_id` is getting as far as the browser, there's clearly something very wrong.

Comment: @DaveNewton Ok, sorry guys...

Comment: Regardless, if it's supposed to be a user name, the JavaScript call will need quotes as djenga49 states.

Comment: @NickBrunt - It wasn't you, it was frustration that it was so obvious but we couldn't convince the OP to give that to us.

Comment: @JaredFarrish No problem, just came across wrong.

Comment: @NickBrunt - Image shoulders slumping when I read that, and you'll understand the sentiment. `:D`

Comment: @Brandon Tilley Thanks you were right as well.. I just didn't get the first part of your answer - sorry for this..Thought it was wrapped correclty.. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update to match new answer:

you need to put quotes around your variables. `($val_id)` probably works because you're retrieving an id which I'm guessing is an integer, so it's a valid JavaScript literal.

`($mes_id)` probably doesn't work because you're getting strings back but not wrapped with quotes, so they aren't valid JavaScript literals.

so usernames will be joe and shmoe, javascript becoems
`addns(joe)` and `addns(shmoe)`, which is probably not what you want. You want `addns("joe")` and `addns("shmoe")`.

Also note once you fix this is an XSS vulnerability if users can choose their username.

Comment: Bingo ! Thanks so much to you and all the rest for comments - indeed, it's a string so ($mes_id) needs to be wrapped in quotes...

Answer (score 1):

See here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php

> Using single quotes will print the variable name, not the value
>
> `echo 'foo is $foo'; // foo is $foo`

I can't see how you're using the wrong quotes to be honest, other than if the JavaScript function requires them, so just to make everything simple, try this:

```
 //FIRST FOREACH CALL PROPERLY
 foreach($membs_id as $val_id) {
 echo "<a href='javascript:addms(\"".$val_id."\")'><img src='".$pcheck."' width='66' height='68'
 border='1' class='currmem'/></a>&nbsp;";
 }


//THIS ONE DOESN'T 
foreach($membs as $mes_id) {
echo "<a href='javascript:addns(\"".$mes_id."\")'>".$mes_id."</a>&nbsp;";
}
```